# How can print out a triangle using serlvet to a jsp/html page

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, for-loop

What I'm trying to to is create a triangle using a for loop and return it to a jsp or html page using servlet. I was able to do it when returning multiple values. Here is my code

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        int num = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("num"));
        String procedure = request.getParameter("procedure_type");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

if (procedure.equalsIgnoreCase("f")) {
                out.write("Fibonacci values "
                        + "<br>"
                        + fibo(num));
        }
```

I have this method of fibonacci

```
public static String fibo(int n) {
        String result = "";
        int num1 = 1;
        int num2 = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            num2 = num2 + num1;
            num1 = num2 - num1;
            result = result + " " + num1;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

How can i format my triangle method so that it returns the whole triangle to a servlet htmlpage?

```
 public static void triangle(int n) {
for (int i = 0; i < n + 1; i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < n + 1; j++) {
                        if (i + j < numn+1) {
                            System.out.println(" ");
                        } else {
                            System.out.println("* ");
                        }
                    }
                    System.out.println("");
                }
}
```

When i format the return to a string it prints the asterisk on a single line

incorrect output is looks like this

```
************
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is to translate the formatting of the Strings to html. You can use textarea then you don't need to use `&nbsp;` and `<br>`:

```
public static void printTriangle(int n, PrintWriter out) {
  out.println("<textarea readonly style=\"font-family:monospace;\">");  
  for (int i = 0; i < n + 1; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < n + 1; j++) {
      if (i + j < numn+1) {
         out.print(" ");
      } else {
         out.print("*");
      }
    }
    out.println();
  }
  out.println("</textarea>");
}
```

Alternative:

```
public static void printTriangle(int n, PrintWriter out) {
  out.println("<div class=\"triangle-container\">");  
  for (int i = 0; i < n + 1; i++) {
    out.println("<div class=\"triangle-line\">");
    for (int j = 0; j < n + 1; j++) {
      if (i + j < numn+1) {
         out.print("<span> </span>");
      } else {
         out.print("<span>*</span>");
      }
    }
    out.println("</div>");
  }
  out.println("</div>");
}
```

Like that you can easily style the triangle with CSS.